# Flask Forms if statement return

Tags: python, flask

I am building a flask app and when I create a fee_handler route I keep getting an error even though I've built one like this in the past. 
I'm not sure what the issue is here.

```
@app.route('/handle_form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def fee_handler():
    if request.method == "POST":
        x = request.form['x']
        y = request.form['y']
        z = request.form['z']
        a = request.form['a']
        fee.feeCreation(x, y, z, a)
        return render_template('result.html', x=x, y=y, z=z, a=a)
```

`TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

If I move the return to be in line with the `if`, I get a local variable error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not returning anything if the request method is `GET`, I assume? Of course you'll get an error if you're trying to return the variables `x, y, z and a` outside the scope of your `if` statement as they won't be defined.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense, I just checked and I it is a `GET`, but I want to make it a `POST`, how do I achieve that?

Comment: `POST` will be the request type when the user submits the form; at least that's how it *should* work..

Comment: I figured it out, my `HTML` has an error in it, but def appreciate your input!

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it may be best to create two routes: one to serve the form, and the other to receive the values and render them back to the user:

```
@app.route('/enter_values', methods=['GET'])
def enter_values():
   return flask.render_template('form_html.html')

@app.route('/handle_form', methods=['POST'])
def fee_handler():
  x = request.form['x']
  y = request.form['y']
  z = request.form['z']
  a = request.form['a']
  fee.feeCreation(x, y, z, a)
  return render_template('result.html', x=x, y=y, z=z, a=a)
```

In the `form_html.html` template, ensure that the form `action` parameter points to `/handle_form`:

```
<form method='POST' action = '/handle_form'>
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: I had already set it up this way, left the form handle out of the original question, the issue was that I had put `methods` instead of `method`, this syntax error was causing my request to default to `GET` which is what flask will do apparently. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use default values and then push your return statement outside the if condition.

**Ex:**

```
@app.route('/handle_form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def fee_handler():
    x, y, z, a = None, None, None, None
    if request.method == "POST":
        x = request.form['x']
        y = request.form['y']
        z = request.form['z']
        a = request.form['a']
        fee.feeCreation(x, y, z, a)
    return render_template('result.html', x=x, y=y, z=z, a=a)
```